# Wordpress + Woocommerce + Ultimate Member. Update customer fields with ultimate member registration form data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have function that should update customer meta fields with data received from ultimate member plugin form. Unfortunatelly it's not working. Here is the code:

```
add_action ('um_post_registration_save', 'custom_update_profile',99, 2);
function custom_update_profile ($user_id) {
    /*$user_id = um_profile_id();*/
    global $ultimatemember;
    um_fetch_user( $user_id );

    $profilefirstname = um_user( 'first_name' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $profilefirstname );

    $profilelastname = um_user( 'last_name' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $profilelastname );

    $profilecompany = um_user( 'business_name' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $profilecompany );

    $profileaddress1= um_user( 'street_address_1' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $profileaddress1 );

    $profilecity= um_user( 'city' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $profilecity);

    $profilestate= um_user( 'state' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', $profilestate);

    $profilezip_code= um_user( 'zip_code' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $profilezip_code);

    $profilecountry= um_user( 'country' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', $profilecountry);

    $profileemail= um_user( 'user_email' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $profileemail);

    $profilephone= um_user( 'phone_number' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $profilephone);

    $profilepassword= um_user( 'haslo' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_password', $profilepassword);

    return $user_id;
}
```

Comment: Can you indicate in what way it is not working? Show or describe the actual output or results you get, and explain how it is different from the desired results.

Comment: Ok. I'm using Ultimate Member plugin to register new customers in my store on register page. If user fills registration fields on that page all his data should be assigned to wocommerce's meta. So if someone fill his first_name it should be assigned to billing_first_name of woocommerce customer data. Unfortunatelly those data are not linking.